# How to consolidate row with gaps using Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data having a start date (and time), a end date (and time) a value and an identifier.

for instance I could have such rows (I left out the date value for breivety) :

- id: 5, start: 00:00, end: 12:00, value: 50
- id: 6, start: 00:00, end: 08:00, value: 60
- id: 7, start: 08:00, end: 20:00, value: 70
- id: 8, start: 22:00, end: 23:00, value: 80
- id: 9, start: 00:00, end: 24:00, value: 90
- id: 10, start: 05:00, end: 07:00, value: 100

Then I'd like to query the best (**smaller id** is **better**) matches which have value between 00:00 and 24:00 and not overlapping each other.

So it would result in:

- start: 00:00, end: 12:00, value: 50 (from id 5)
- start: 12:00, end: 20:00, value: 70 (from id 7, but cropped not to overlap previous match)
- start: 22:00, end: 23:00, value: 80 (from id 8)
- start: 20:00, end: 22:00, value: 90 (from id 9, but cropped not to overlap previous matches)
- start: 23:00, end: 24:00, value: 90 (from id 9 again, but cropped not to overlap previous matches)
- Nothing more, there are already values for the full datetime range.

There is no smallest unit of time (like one hour) so I can't generate a "tally table" with values from 00:00 to 24:00 and retrieves the best match for each unit of time (like 00:00 - 01:00).

There is no guarantee there will be enough values to fill the datetime range.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Your title says SQL Server (i.e. Microsoft), tags say Oracle - which one is it?

Comment: You could achieve this with a cursor.